HP printer is installed with hplip but communication error
HP Deskjet 2755e and Ubuntu 22.04 and hplip 3.24.4.
Printer is connected via USB. Installed using hplip device manager and the USB option.
hp-check shows the device under USB devices but indicates there is a communication error. HP Device manager also shows a communication error in Status.
In addition, another instance of the printer shows up in Settings/Printers and in hp-check that is not installed via hplip and doesn't appear in HP Device manager.
I removed the second printer instance in Settings/Printers, it disappeared from the printer list, and reappeared shortly thereafter.
When I was running the printer using wireless connection, I had the same problem with multiple instances of the printer appearing. I had installed it using hplip and its network address.
What could be generating all these different instances of this printer?

I uninstalled the USB printer instance and reinstalled using hplip as a network printer and was able to print. However, the print dialog showed me two printers: Deskjet_2700 (installed with hplip) and HP_Deskjet_2700_series_10353B. Then I printed another document and now have a third printer in the printer list: HP_Deskjet_2700_series_10353B@HPBC0FF310353B.local. What is generating all these printer queues?

Results of hp-check show all three queues.
